# C++ _tWinMain run more than one times?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

Im using DuiLib and Cef.
and I fond that my _tWinMain called 2 times.
1:When I open app,main() was called;
2 When I Create a Window, main() was called 2nd.

here is some code:

```
vector<wstring> StartArgs;
map<wstring, wstring> argsMaps;
void GetArgMap() {
    for (int i = 1; i < StartArgs.size(); ++i) {
        wstring argStr = StartArgs[i];
        vector<wstring> argVec;
        split(argStr, L':', argVec);
        if (argVec.size() >= 2) {
            wstring k = argVec[0];
            wstring v = argVec[1];
            argsMaps.insert(map<wstring, wstring>::value_type(k,v));
        }
    }
}

wstring GetArgForKey(wstring key) {

    wstring ret = argsMaps[key];
    if (lstrcmpW(ret.c_str(), L"")) {
        return ret;
    }
    else {
        return L"null";
    }
}

bool CheckParamAvialble(wstring param) {
    if (lstrcmpW(param.c_str(), L"null")) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{   

    ShowMessageBox(L"this is test alert!", L"WARNING");
    int argCount = 0;
    LPWSTR cmdline = GetCommandLine();
    //cmdline is  [m:1 h:0 a:500000 n:xxx c:xxx u:usera o:TOKEN]
    LPWSTR* szArgList = CommandLineToArgvW(cmdline, &argCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < argCount; ++i) {
        wstring a = szArgList[i];
        StartArgs.push_back(a);
    }

    if (argCount >= 7) {
        wstring mString = GetArgForKey(L"m");
        if (!CheckParamAvialble(mString))
        {
            ShowMessageBox(L"arg m is wrong！", L"Error");
            return 0;
        }
        /*
            do something with other args
        */
            CPaintManagerUI::SetInstance(hInstance);
            InitResource();
            HRESULT Hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
            if (FAILED(Hr)) return 0;
            CefMainArgs args(hInstance);
            CefRefPtr<SimpleApp> app(new SimpleApp);
            int exitCode = CefExecuteProcess(args, app, NULL);
            if (exitCode >= 0)
            {
                return exitCode;
            }
            CefSettings settings;
            CefInitialize(args, settings, app.get(), NULL);
            CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line;
            command_line = CefCommandLine::CreateCommandLine();
            command_line->AppendSwitch("no-proxy-server");
            MainForm *pFrame = new MainForm(_T("Forms\\MA_MainForm.xml"));
            if (pFrame == NULL) return 0;
            pFrame->Create(NULL, _T("MainForm"), UI_WNDSTYLE_FRAME, WS_EX_STATICEDGE | WS_EX_APPWINDOW, 0, 0, 600, 800);//when progrom go here,i got 2nd MessageBox[this is test alert!]
            pFrame->CenterWindow();
            CefRunMessageLoop();
            CefShutdown();
            return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        ShowMessageBox(L"something wrong and exit", L"Error");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and the strange thing is
2nd call main() wont trigger my break point, it just show messagebox[this is test alert!] again.
and if i show another window, it will show 3rd messagebox[this is test alert!]
just show the messagebox multiple times,no break,no exception.
thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no way the code you have shown can cause the behavior you have described. So, it has to be in code you have not shown, or it has to be a bad build produced by your toolchain. Your `_tWinMain()` should only be called 1 time, at app startup. Creating windows has nothing to do with `_tWinMain()` being called.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I find that CEF cause that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read over how the [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage) works?  It will create multiple processes, normally by spawning additional copies of the main executable.  When that happens, you'll get a different process displaying your "this is a test alert" dialog.  Since this is a different process, your breakpoints will not be hit unless you have your debugger configured to debug any spawned child processes.

The result is that what you see is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I find that CEF cause that.